# Reflection stopped working after project update to Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Here is official sample from Microsoft (to work with wide tiles in wp 7.8):

```
// Get the new FlipTileData type.
Type flipTileDataType = Type.GetType( "Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData, Microsoft.Phone" );

// Get the ShellTile type so we can call the new version of "Update" that takes the new Tile templates.
Type shellTileType = Type.GetType( "Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile, Microsoft.Phone" );
```

It works in wp7.8 and in wp8 when compiled as wp7 app. But after converting project target to wp8 both requests return null. Why?

Comment: You can call those types directly, you don't need to use reflection for them on WP8.

Comment: I know, but I want to keep one tile manager class for wp7.1 - wp8.

Comment: Then I'd recommend something like [MangoPollo](http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/)

Comment: MangoPollo doesn't work on 71. Already tested it. And my class will be much more functional.