# FlipTileData reflection stopped working with Win8

Tags: reflection, windows-phone-8, tiles

I want to create one universal method to create tile in WP7.8 and WP8.

When I'm using reflection (like Microsoft suggest):

```
// Get the new FlipTileData type.
Type flipTileDataType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData, Microsoft.Phone");
var UpdateTileData = flipTileDataType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(null);
```

It's working on WP7.8.

But after upgrade my project to Win8 flipTileDataType is null.
But then constructor

```
 Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData UpdateTileData = new Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData();
```

is working.

So, how can I build one universal version for both systems?

Answer (score 0):

Do not upgrade project to Windows Phone 8. Develop it as Windows Phone 7.8 app. The tile will work correctly on WP8 devices. I found the  [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822806/reflection-stopped-working-after-project-update-to-windows-phone-8) before and it looks like there is no solution.

Comment: I have to prepare second version of xap dedicated W8 only, so I have to upgrade project.

Comment: In this case you should use direct call to the Tile API and different source file (as in my case) or use conditional compilation options.